# Using scikit-learn to decide if a given text is similar to previously learnt texts

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a newbie to skilearn.

What I want to do is quite simple - just feed my model with a bunch of similar texts.

Then, I want to be able to give it a new text, and see if it is similar to the existing texts in the dataset.

How should this be done?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One good aproach might be using cosine similarity. This is a very good tutorial for starting:
[Machine Learning :: Cosine Similarity for Vector Space Models (Part III)](http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/)

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach would be a Bayesian Classifier, like the ones used for SPAM detection. Take a look at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) link to learn more about them.